# Woocommerce Custom Product Options Using Jetengine/Crocoblock

Tags: woocommerce, jet-engine, customising

I am trying to find out whether Jetengine/JetForm Builder can add custom fields to woocommerce products to achieve customisable products for customers to purchase.

For example, if I am selling customisable mugs, I want them to be able to fill in a text field to type their name or to upload their company logo and this information then gets attached to the purchase order for the store manager to see and thereafter make the customised product with the correct information.

This information will also need to come up on the customer's account pages to show them what they typed in or uploaded.

I hope this makes sense.

I know jet engine allows you to add meta boxes to products however I cannot seem to get this field to display on the front-end of the website for the customers to fill in their names or upload their logo for the custom order.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask Jetengine/JetForm Builder about their functionalities. Here we ask and resolve technical questions related to coding.

It is possible to achieve what you enquire through coding.

It will require the following:

- A text input field to be displayed on product pages
- A uploads input field to be displayed on product pages
- A code to store the input data from both fields
- A code to display the stored data backend in order details
- A code to display the stored data on accounts order page
- OPTIONAL: A code to display the stored data in the order email

These are all topics that have been/are being addressed on stack overflow and can be found through extensive searching.